# Complex analysis of improper integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

Please confirm if my solution is correct: Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{2}+a^{2}}dx$.

Let $f(z)=\frac{\log z}{z^{2}+a^{2}}dz$ and $z=\pm ai$ and $ai\in C$ Hence, $\mid z\mid=a$, therefore choose $R>a$

$[\Rightarrow\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log z}{z^{2}+a^{2}}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\log z}{z^{2}+a^{2}}dz]$

Taking the Residue will give us

$[\mathrm{Res}\left[ f,ai\right]=2\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow ai}\dfrac{(z-ai)(\log z)}{(z-ai)(z+ai)}]$

Applying the L'Hopital Rule

$[\Rightarrow 2\pi i\lim_{z\rightarrow ai}\dfrac{(z-ai)(\log z)}{(z+ai)(z-ai)}=2\pi i\left[ \lim_{z\rightarrow ai}\dfrac{1}{z}\right] =\dfrac{2\pi i}{ai}]$

However, we will have

$[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{2}+a^{2}}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{a}\right)=\dfrac{\pi}{a}]$

Taking the Real part of the function, we will have
$[\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{2}+a^{2}}dx=\dfrac{\pi}{a}]$